# List array of array in class model flutter

Tags: flutter

How to create class model in flutter if List Array of Array have 2 type data
Example

"value" : [["Water Melon", "Apple", 10, 23]]

```
@JsonSerializable()
class GetReportBodyData {
  String type;
  String title;
  List<String> headers;
  List<List<int>> value = new List<List<int>>();

  GetReportBodyData({this.type, this.title, this.headers, this.value});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'GetReportBodyData{type: $type, title: $title, header: $headers, value: $value}';
  }

  factory GetReportBodyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GetReportBodyData(
        type: json["type"],
        title: json["title"],
        headers: json["header"] != null ? List<String>.from(json["header"]) :[],
        value: List<List<int>>.from(json["value"])
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic>toJson() => {
    "type": type,
    "title": title,
    "header": headers,
    "value": value
  };
}
```

Comment: @Abdullah Arshad

Comment: you can write `List<List<var>> value = new List<List<var>>();` and also change in from json with var

Comment: @JahidulIslam, so from json it should be replaced by var?

Comment: Why you don't want to use the `dynamic` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class example {
    List<List> value;

    example({this.value});

    example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        if (json['value'] != null) {
            value = new List<List>();
            json['value'].forEach((v) { value.add(new List.fromJson(v)); });
        }
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.value != null) {
      data['value'] = this.value.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
        return data;
    }
}

class Value {


    Value({});

    Value.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: hi @Abdullah Arshad, Thanks for answer but isn't working in my model